# How to create trigger which update 1 column then another column updated too?

Tags: mysql, sql, triggers

I'm confused that How to create trigger when I update 1 column, the other columns also update too [ all of the columns are in the same Table]

This is my Table

```
create table VIP( 
    VipID                int identity (10001,1)  not null, 
    PackageID            Char(10) not null, 
    Vip_Expire           Date     null,
    DateofTransaction    date     null, 
constraint VIP_PK primary key(VipID), 
constraint VIP_FK1 foreign key(MemberID)  
  references MEMBER(MemberID), 
constraint VIP_FK2 foreign key(PackageID)   
  references Package(PackageID)
```

I need to update PackageID then

1.DateofTransaction is day that u update
2.Vip_expire is day that u update + Packagedays[Data in PackageTable]

I try to use this Code in my Trigger and try to update like this.

TRIGGER

```
create trigger VIP_UPDATE on VIP
after update
.
.
.
select packagedays
from package
where @packagedays = packagedays 
    update vip
    set PackageId = @newpackage,
        Dateoftransaction = CONVERT (date, GETDATE()),
        Vip_Expire = dateadd(day, @packagedays, CONVERT (date, GETDATE()))
    where PackageID = @oldPackage and
          Vip_expire = @OldVip_expire and
          Dateoftransaction = @OldDateT
```

FOR EXAMPLE 
[image]

I need to update PackageID from '1002' to '1003' which 
'1003' has 120 days [VIPID 10001]

so the result that should be is 
VIPID 10001
MEMBERID 620000
PackageID 1003
VipExpire 2019-08-01
DateofTransaction 2019-04-03

Comment: Please post sample data, your UPDATE statement and how the sample data should look like after the UPDATE statement.

Comment: i already add the example in my Post 

Could u please check it again and help me please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you need something like this:

```
create trigger VIP_UPDATE
after update on VIP
for each row
begin
  if (new.PackageID <> old.PackageID) then
    set new.DateofTransaction = current_date();
    set new.Vip_Expire = (
        select current_date() + interval p.Packagedays day
        from Package p
        where p.PackageID = new.PackageID
    );
  end if;
end
```

When you want to change columns from the same row, which is updated, you don't write an UPDATE statement in the trigger. You just SET `NEW.column_name` to the new value.

Comment: i can't use code 'FOR EACH ROW' in my dtb but i use your code and adapt it.
Now i can update package then Vip_expire and Dateoftransaction are updated 
BUT!! it effects in all row in my table

 I need it to effect only 1 rows

This is code that i use to update

Update vip
set packageid = '1003'
where vipid = '10001'

Comment: I'm not sure I undestand your comment correctly. `FOR EACH ROW` doesn't mean "for each row in the table" - it means "for each **affected** row". So if you UPDATE only one row, the trigger will change only that row.